# Replace segment of URL in place

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with a line:

```
value = "http://jenkins/my/job/jobname/4564/artifact"
```

Now I would like to replace the number (`4564`) with a different one via sed.

I tried:

```
sed 's|http[s]?:\/\/.*\/job\/jobname\/([0-9]+)\/artifact|8945|g'
```

In all tools I can match the group just fine but I cannot seem to figure out how to tell sed to replace the one and only group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sed 's@\(/jobname/\)[0-9]\+@\1whatever@'
```

- you have chosen `|` as separator of sed's `s` command, then you don't have to escape those `/`, such as `http://`
- default sed's regex is BRE, you have to escape `+` and `()` to give them special meaning.
- In your codes, the group doesn't make sense, because it is the part you want to replace. If you want to save some typing, you should place the group on the parts you want to keep in final result.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you cannot replace a group selectively?

Comment: @abergmeier what I want to say I have posted in answer. Usually you make a group, you want to reference it later. In your codes, you grouped the part you want to replace.

Comment: That was exactly my thinking: Making a group and replacing _that_ group. Grouping things, to not getting them replaced feels backwards to me. But I probably need to read the docs of sed \ replacement.

Comment: Ok, `sed 's|\(/job/jobname/\)[0-9]\+|\1whatever|'` works. Could you please elaborate, why the `http[s]?://.*` portion makes it not work?

Comment: @abergmeier I have to repeat the words in my answer once again. sed uses BRE as default, you have to escape chars which in regex context have special meanings,  to give them the special meaning. here in your example, `?` is another one. without escaping, in BRE, it indicates literal `?`. I suggest you that read some regex tutorial.